# ffmpeg sometimes not working for splitted videos-moov atom not found

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using below command to reverse video-

```
{"-i", files[i].getAbsolutePath(), "-vf", "reverse", "-af", "areverse", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

I occasionally gets below error-

> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers\n 
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100\n[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xec427000] **moov atom not found**\n/storage/emulated/0/Movies/.VideoSplit/split_video010.mp4:
>   Invalid data found when processing input

By what i have researched-

> moov atom is a container for the information that describes a movie’s
>   data...Generally speaking, only metadata is stored in a movie atom.
>   Sample data for the movie, such as audio or video samples, are
>   referenced in the movie atom, but are not contained in it.

The videos which I am reversing are **splitted videos** from a main video which I have splitted using below command-

```
{ "-i", inputFilePath, "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "22", "-map", "0", "-segment_time", "6", "-g", "9", "-sc_threshold", "0", "-force_key_frames", "expr:gte(t,n_forced*6)", "-f", "segment", outputFilePath};
```

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: Have you found any answer??